# Secure FTP Port between Filezilla and Godaddy

Tags: ftp, firewall, port

I recently upgraded to Filezilla 3.0.x

I am getting "filezilla error: Failed to retrieve directory listing godaddy" errors from Filezilla which i believe is because of a blocked port on my firewall

1) Does Godaddy support the new filezilla "use explicit FTP over TLS if available" (i have a ticket in with godaddy as well but thats not going to happen quickly)
1a) bonus if it require configuration where do i do that

2) what port does this new "use explicit FTP over TLS if available" use

I've tried port 22 21 990

I also see the firewall is kicking out

```
dstport="50141"
dstport="50158"
dstport="50180"
dstport="50321"
dstport="50498"
dstport="50723"
dstport="50978"
```

But i'm not sure what the proper port is

Additional information:

Filezilla was able to get the SHA thumbprint of my godaddy server so there was some sort of talking going on but it just hangs on the retrieving directory information

Comment: The port used is configured by you when you make the initial connection.  Verify you are using the port that GoDaddy uses for SFTP connections.

Comment: Thats kinda of what im asking what port is that

Comment: The port you tell Filezilla to use when you connect to the website or the port GoDaddy uses by default unless you change it?  This seems like an easy case of just forwarding the ports you saw firewall blocking traffic on.

Comment: I am aware I just want to get the correct answer so im not opening more ports than are needed

Comment: Your question is about FTP, yet you use [tag:sftp] tag. Make sure you understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

With FTP protocol (in passive mode), you need to have port range for data transfers (directory listing and file transfers) opened on the firewall in additional to port 21 (for control connection).

That's why you see number of ports in range 50xxx rejected on the firewall. That's likely the range your FTP server is configured to use for data transfers.

To understand how the FTP passive mode works, see my answer at [What is the difference between active and passive FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1699145/850848#27820711)

---

The "Explicit FTP over TLS" uses the same port as plain FTP, the 21.

---

Port 22 is for SSH/SFTP. That's a completely different protocol to FTP. Note that FileZilla (as most other "FTP" clients) supports both FTP (including FTP over TLS) and SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

**Encrypted FTP is not compatible with firewall helpers** that analyze the command session to allow data connections.

As such, you need a firewall that allows *all* outgoing connections, because FTP has no specified range of ports for data connections. They could be allocated from the entire range of valid TCP ports.

The symptoms you’re experiencing—successful login, but no directory listings—clearly show that data connections are not successful.

Answer (score -1):

You must enable SSH on Godaddy site first.

Port 22

Comment: You ask about FTP over TLS. Port 22 is for SSH/SFTP.